# How to make label column in pandas dataframe while grouping by counts?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the category column similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'category': ['POLITICS','WELLNESS', 'ENTERTAINMENT', 'TRAVEL','POLITICS', 'ENTERTAINMENT','POLITICS'],
       'dates': ["2013-01-31","2013-01-31","2013-02-02", "2013-02-02","2013-02-03", "2013-02-03", "2013-02-04"]}
df1=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['category', 'dates'])
df1
```

I want a dictionary which would be like this  for some 30+ different categories, which I can later use to make another column, label.

```
label_dict = {'POLITICS':0, 'ENTERTAINMENT':1, 'WELLNESS':2 ,'TRAVEL':3, .....}
df1['label'] = df1['category'].map(label_dict).fillna(6).astype(int)
```

I want my labelling begin with the category containing most counts (e.g. 'POLITICS', 'ENTERTAINMENT' and so on).

I have tried this:

```
df1["category"].value_counts().to_dict()
```

which gives me

```
{'POLITICS': 3, 'ENTERTAINMENT': 2, 'WELLNESS': 1, 'TRAVEL': 1}
```

How can I create label_dict?  i.e. how can I assign the labels  - eg. 0 instead of 3, 1 instead of 2, 2 instead of 1 and 3 instead of 1?

my final dataframe should look like this:

```
   category        dates       label
0   POLITICS        2013-01-31  0
1   WELLNESS        2013-01-31  1
2   ENTERTAINMENT   2013-02-02  2
3   TRAVEL          2013-02-02  3
4   POLITICS        2013-02-03  0
5   ENTERTAINMENT   2013-02-03  2
6   POLITICS        2013-02-04  0
```

thank you.

Comment: are you looking for [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) ?

Comment: just `pd.factorize(df1['category'])[0]`

Comment: thank you, it works only I cant get these in order by counts. e.g. ENTERTAINMENT should have label 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `value_count` method to get the counts of each category. Then `reset_index`. This will give you a `DataFrame` where index is the label you want to use.

**Example**:

```
counts = df1["category"].value_counts().reset_index()
counts.columns = ['category', 'count']

label_dict = counts['category'].to_dict()
# invert the dictionary to have categories as keys and counts as values
label_dict = {v: k for k, v in label_dict.items()}

df1['label'] = df1['category'].map(label_dict).fillna(6).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
d = (pd.factorize(
    df1['category'].value_counts()
    .sort_values(ascending=False)
    .reset_index()['category']))
label_dict = {x: y for x, y in (zip(d[1], d[0]))}
df1.assign(label = df1['category'].map(label_dict))
```

Output:

```
        category       dates  label
0       POLITICS  2013-01-31      0
1       WELLNESS  2013-01-31      2
2  ENTERTAINMENT  2013-02-02      1
3         TRAVEL  2013-02-02      3
4       POLITICS  2013-02-03      0
5  ENTERTAINMENT  2013-02-03      1
6       POLITICS  2013-02-04      0
```

Comment: yep thats what I'm looking for. however I'm getting NaNs for labels with your code, not sure why.

Comment: I have just tried it again with your dataframe and everything went fine. Maybe, your are using an old pandas version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function to map the values of the category and the label_dict

```
df1["label"] = df1["category"].map(label_dict)
```

Comment: I know how to  create a column from a dictionary. What I need is how to create the dictionary with labels as keys?